# Run 2 programs at same time..using batch? (same folder)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was trying to write a batch script that would make it possible to run 2 exe, one after the other. It needs to be in the same folder because I will deploy this folder, so I can't use the `cd "C: ..."`

My other issue is that the first executable opens a process so if I open it normally, it opens a cmd window for a second and then closes itself again so when I wrote the script, the script stays stuck in between and doesn't continue running.

```
@echo off
cd NF_Data
cd Managed
start "Brain.BA.Server.exe"
//I get stuck here - the exe opens another cmd and just sits there
cd..
cd..
start "NF.exe"
exit
```

So I end up having 2 cmds open and can't do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

The batch can be reduced to the following lines:

```
@echo off
start .\NF_Data\Managed\Brain.BA.Server.exe
start NF.exe
```

`start "Anything.exe"` will just open a new command prompt with the window-title "Anything.exe".

So you need to remove the double quotes to start `Anything.exe`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably because the `Start` command is expecting the first doublequoted string to be a title.

Try the following, *which uses an empty title, and prevents the need for the `CD` command too*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Start "" /D "NF_Data\Managed" "Brain.BA.Server.exe"
Start "" "NF.exe"
```

*Note the use of `Start`'s `/D` option, which runs your `Brain.BA.Server.exe` file with the `NF_Data\Managed` drive as its working folder. This means that you don't need to change back to the initial working folder to run the `NF.exe` file.*